# PHP Header Location Not Working Properly

Tags: php, html, forms, radio-button

Can someone point me out why the below isn't working? It only redirects to the first location even if I choose different radio buttons.

PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    if (!empty($_POST['electronics'])) {

        if ($_POST['electronics'] = "camera") {
            header("location: camera.php");
            exit();
        }
        if ($_POST['electronics'] = "cell") {
            header("location: cellphones.php");
            exit();
        }
        if ($_POST['electronics'] = "cable") {
            header("location: cables.php");
            exit();
        }
        if ($_POST['electronics'] = "tv") {
            header("location: tv.php");
            exit();
        }
    }

...
```

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="radio"  name="electronics" value="cell"/>
    <input type="radio"  name="electronics" value="camera"/>
    <input type="radio"  name="electronics" value="cable"/>
    <input type="radio"  name="electronics" value="tv"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: `= !== ===` is the best I can come up with

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use the comparison operator `==` instead of `=`

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    if (!empty($_POST['electronics'])) {

        if ($_POST['electronics'] == "camera") {
            header("location: camera.php");
        }
        else if ($_POST['electronics'] == "cell") {
            header("location: cellphones.php");
        }
        else if ($_POST['electronics'] == "cable") {
            header("location: cables.php");
        }
        else if ($_POST['electronics'] == "tv") {
            header("location: tv.php");
        }
    }

...
```

Also, the `exit()` is also redundant as you are already redirecting to another page.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Will accept. Okay will remove exit also.

Answer (score 2):

`=` is assignment. `==` is equality. You've confused the two.

Comment: oops I thought I had two. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To add to the other answers, when you use the assignment operator (=) instead of the comparison operators (== or ===), the assignment is passed from right to left.

So the following is true:

```
"camera" == $_POST['electronics'] = "camera"
```

Which in your case is true enough to satisfy the `if`

It's the same behaviour that lets you make multiple assignments with one value.

eg:

```
$foo = $bar = 10;
```

`$foo` and `$bar` are both assigned 10.